# How to secure a camel cxf endpoint (https) in FUSE 7.6?

Tags: https, apache-camel, jbossfuse, undertow, camel-cxf

We have been using camel-cxf service endpoints for multiple applications. They works well. Recently we have a need to secure these service endpoints. Therefore, we are adding   `<httpu:engine-factory>` configuration to the camel-context.xml.

We also configured FUSE 7.6 server to have the secure port at 8183 by setting

- [FUSE 7.6 Install]/etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg file:

org.osgi.service.http.port = 8181
org.osgi.service.http.port.secure = 8183
org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file = ${karaf.etc}/undertow.xml
org.ops4j.pax.web.session.cookie.httpOnly = false
org.ops4j.pax.web.session.cookie.secure = true

- [FUSE 7.6 Install]/etc/undertow.xml is correctly configured to point
  to right keystore and truststore, etc.

Following is the camel-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
     xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
     xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
     xmlns:httpu="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-undertow/configuration"
     xsi:schemaLocation="         
     http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0             
     https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security 
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd 
     http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration 
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd 
     http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-undertow/configuration 
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-undertow.xsd">
     
     <bean class="com.mycom.myapp.CamelRequestProcessor" id="myProcessor"/>
     <cxf:cxfEndpoint address="{{MY_HOST}}:8185{{MY_SVC_ADDRESS}}"
          bus="auditBus" id="myWebServiceEndpoint"
          serviceClass="com.mycom.myapp.MyWebServiceEndpoint" wsdlURL="wsdl/mySvc.wsdl"/>
 
    <httpu:engine-factory bus="cxf">
        <httpu:engine port="8185">
            <httpu:tlsServerParameters secureSocketProtocol="$(MY_SECURE_SOCKET_PROTOCOL)">
                <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="$(MY_KEY_PASSWORD)">
                    <sec:keyStore file="$(MY_KEYSTORE)" password="$(MY_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)" type="JKS"/>
                </sec:keyManagers>
                <sec:trustManagers>
                    <sec:keyStore file="$(MY_TRUSTSTORE)" password="$(MY_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD)" type="JKS"/>
                </sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:clientAuthentication required="true" want="true"/>
            </httpu:tlsServerParameters>
        </httpu:engine>
    </httpu:engine-factory>
    
    <camelContext id="_myCamelContext" useBlueprintPropertyResolver="true" errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">
          <route id="_firstRuote">
               <from id="_from" uri="cxf:bean:myWebServiceEndpoint"/>
               <bean id="_processor" method="process" ref="myProcessor"/>
               <to id="_to4" uri="direct:otherEndpoints"/>
          </route>  
     </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

After we add `<httpu:engine-factory/>`section, the code is built and deployed to FUSE 7.6. Everything goes well. There is no error in the log, and the bundle starts normally. When I inspected the service at https://myhost:8183/cxf, the service is displayed in browser

```
Endpoint address: https://my host:8185/cxf/MyWebServiceEndpoint/<br>
WSDL : {namespace}MyWebServiceEndpoint   <--This is a link-->
```

However, ***when I click the WSDL link, it spins a few seconds, then displays "Unable to connect"***. It should display the WSDL file.
The browser address bar does point to the correct URL
https://myhost:8185/cxf/MyWebServiceEndpoint/?wsdl

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way if I don't do the change on /etc/undertow.xml and remove the <httpu:engine-factory/>, this code works. In other words, the issue is how to convert it to https

Answer (score 0):

Your camel-cxf endpoint has
<sec:clientAuthentication required="true" want="true"/>
Which means your client(in this case a browser to load the wsdl) also needs to provide the private key(keystore).

Did you import truststore/keystore that you used for the camel-cxf endpoint into your browser?

Comment: I didn't import truststore/keystore. I shouldn't to, right?

Comment: I mean you should.

Comment: The certificate is already downloaded to browser when I tried to view available cxf services (i.e., https://myhost:8183/cxf)

Comment: even if I have <sec:clientAuthentication required="false" want="false"/>. wsdl file still can not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The undertow configuration has to specify host as the following, which makes the port accessible:
<httpu:engine host="0.0.0.0" port="8185">